# MySQL and PHP with Google Maps - Data source only works locally not when accessing from an http url

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-markers

This code seems to work just fine when using the xml file (generated from php) locally. i.e. /phpsqlajax_genxml.php

However when I try and use the same xml file externally it won't populate. i.e. http://brewslocal.com/phpsqlajax_genxml.php

Any help as to why? Attached below is the code I am using.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="beer-128.png"  >
<title>BrewsLocal - Find More Local Breweries</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {

      Brewery: {
        icon: '/Logomakr_5xi5EC.png'

      },
      Brewpub: {
        icon: '/Logomakr_5xi5EC.png'

      }

    };

var gmarkers1 = [];

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var currentlat = getParameterByName('lat');
var currentlng = getParameterByName('lng');



    function initialize() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(currentlat , currentlng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'      
  });


      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("/phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("longAddress");
          var lat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
          var lng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var logo = markers[i].getAttribute("logo");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<div class='infoblock'><img style='display: block; margin: auto;'src='" + logo + "' height='120px' width='auto'/><h2>" + name + "</h2><a href='/brewery?id=" +
              id + "'>Brewery Page</a><a href='http://www.google.com/maps/?q=" + point
              + "' target='_blank' style='opacity: .8;'>Location</a></div>";
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            type: type,
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
    gmarkers1.push(markers);

   
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });

      
    

    }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }


    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('phpsqlajax_genxml.php') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }




    function doNothing() {}
    //]]>


        </script>
 </head>

    <body onload="initialize()">
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>

  
            <div id="map"></div>
 <div style="    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;" ><h2 id="error"></h2><input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="main-input" placeholder="Enter A Location" required><button type="submit"  onclick="testlocation()" class="btn" id="location-button" >Locate</button></div>

                       
                    </div>


  
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting the Ajax Cross Origin.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

You can use Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in server who serves phpsqlajax_genxml.php, try to add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in the start of phpsqlajax_genxml.php maybe that can help.

Or an alternative approach you can use JSONP (but this needs more development for your case.)